# How to use a SAS Expander

Tags: hard-drive, motherboard, sas

I would like to hookup my mother board to the backplane. Th backplane requires 5 minSAS connectors, for a total of 20 hard disks. My motherboard only supports 2 miniSAS connectors, for a total of 8 hard disks. Can anyone recommand a VMware approved solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You're not fully explaining what you wish to do. In this case, I would use a dedicated SAS HBA to connect to your external chassis. An example would be something like the LSI 9200 or 9205 controllers. I'd leave the motherboard slots alone. How many drives are you trying to address?

Are SURE that your enclosure has minisas connectors? Most enclosures will have SFF-8088 4-lane connectors.

Answer (score 0):

A very old post - but for the sake of similar questions in the future i'll answer it anyway.

> Th backplane requires 5 minSAS connectors, for a total of 20 hard disks. My motherboard only supports 2 miniSAS connectors

That's most often number of ports for average SAS controller, 2 connectors = 8 drives.

> Can anyone recommand a VMware approved solution for this?

VmWare has nothing to do with expanders (ESX or VmWare Workstation). Expander is invisible to operating systems: esx, linux, windows, etc. Some expanders don't even plugin to PCIe, just to power supply (that's how much expander talks to motherboard). It's hardware compatibility between a controller and an expander that matters.

Probably you wanted to ask if your SAS controller/hba on motherboard is compatible with VmWare ESX - that you'll have to check with vmware. If it's LSI based then it's natively supported in ESX. If you talk about VmWare workstation any controller/hba that has drivers for Windows/Linux will work.

> Since you asked "How to use a SAS Expander":

- You connect you HD MiniSAS (further: SFF-8644) motherboard connectors to your expander using 2 identical cables that have: SFF-8644 on one end and SFF-8087 on the other end. I "presume" that your expander has SFF-8087 connectors.
- Now you connect expander to backplane with 5 cables SFF-8087 -> SFF-8644 (same cable as earlier, probably just a bit longer).

This answers your question (presuming few things since you did't specify motherboard nor expander you use, nor version of vmware).

*Additionally:
Read the expander manual to see which are "controller link" ports (usually 1,2 or 0,1 - if you mistake no damage will occur, but disks won't be in "tree" structure (controller->expander->disks, you will see controller->disks). Here's example of correct connection between controller and expander.*

[image: Proper connection between expander and controller shows typical three structure server-controller-expander-drives]

Advice: try to buy expander of the same manufacturer as the controller to avoid weird issues and ping-pong on help-desks when things go south.